# Call fortran dll from java using JNI

Tags: java, windows, fortran, java-native-interface

I have a Fifp.dll in fortran with a simple `void RESET()` function and try to call it from my Java code.
I made a simple java test class:

```
public class TestJni {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("Fifp");
}

public native void RESET();
}
```

I made a .h file from it, and compiled it.
I also made a bridge file myBridge.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TestJni.h"

extern void RESET();

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestJni_RESET(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf("Before DLL call\n");
    RESET();
    printf("After DLL call\n");
}
```

Now I'm not able to compile it. This is the command I tried in a Visual Studio x64 comand prompt:

```
> cl -I"C:\path\to\jdk\include\win32" -I"C:\path\to\jdk\include" myBridge.c
```

and also with a `-FeFifp.dll` option, it gives me the same error:
[LNK2019: unresolved external symbol RESET (and main)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfRFU.png)

So what am I doing wrong ? 
Is there an option to specify the external dll to include ? 
Am I in the right way to perform the `new TestJni().RESET()` call ?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Unfortunatelly the DLL was sent by an other dev team and I can't have more info about it for the moment, maybe I can send email but I don't know what to ask and when I'll get an answer... If I understand your comment, there are symbols in the DLL which are important for me to know to call its function(s) ? the DLL must have been set as externally visible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Prepare a Fifp.DEF file for the prebuilt Fortran DLL.

   ```
   LIBRARY Fifp.dll 
   EXPORTS
     RESET
   ```
2. Create the LIB from DEF.

   ```
   lib /def:Fifp.DEF /OUT:Fifp.lib
   ```
3. Build the FifpBridge.dll from myBridge.c and Fifp.LIB.

   ```
   cl /LD myBridge.c /link Fifp.LIB
   ```
4. Change the Java statement to loadLibrary("FifpBridge"). The bridge will load the Fortran DLL without your intervention.
5. Make sure both FifpBridge.dll and Fifp.dll are available at run time.

Comment: Wonderful ! after hours of headache, you bring me this simple magical solution :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: if it can be helpful for someone else, the third point for me was : cl -I"C:\path\to\jdk\include\win32" -I"C:\path\to\jdk\include" /LD myBridge.c /link Fifp.LIB